# Как считывать определенное количество символов? C++

Tags: c++

Допустим у меня на вход поступают данные вида "11:40", как например в [этой](https://acmp.ru/index.asp?main=task&id_task=331) задаче. Могу ли я сделать какой то посимвольный ввод в целочисленную переменную? То есть, например, в примере "11:40" выделить "11" и присвоить какой либо целочисленной переменной. Такое же сделать с "40". Или придется создавать строку и ее разбивать на нужные фрагменты?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, на самом деле на вход подается два целых и один символ, так и можно считывать:

```
int h, m;
char c;
cin >> h >> c >> m;
```

Или, если память критична, или удобно считывать в символ, то:

```
char get_time()
{
    return 10 * (cin.get() - '0') + (cin.get() - '0');
}

int main()
{       
    
    char hour = get_time();
    cin.ignore(); //пропустить разделитель
    char min = get_time();
    //если нужно целочисленное значение, то использовать (int)hour и (int)min;


}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Считываете строку.
2. Читаете посимвольно.
3. PROFIT.

Вот примерный код преобразования строки в числовое значение минут с начала суток:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main () {
    string str = "11:40";
    int time = ((str[0] - '0') * 10 + (str[1] - '0')) * 60 +
        (str[3] - '0') * 10 + (str[4] - '0');
    cout << time << endl;
}
```

Либо считываете каждый символ через `getchar()`.

Answer (score 0):

Мое решение данной проблемы. Используя ту идею, о которой изначально говорил.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string str = "11:40";
    pair<int, int> time; //time.first - часы, time.second - минуты.
    time.first = stoi(str.substr(0, 2));
    time.second = stoi(str.substr(3, 2));
    cout << time.first << ":" << time.second;
}
```

ну и конечно, в рамках решения данной задачи, надо не забыть учесть ведущие нули в строке, но по факту идея данного решения и нужна была мне.